# How to set default browser in windows 8 using C#?

Tags: c#, browser, windows-8, default

We all have been easily able to do this prior to Windows 8 (in XP/VISTA/WIN7) with few changes in Registry and it was done.

With Windows 8 it's not that easy (I'm yet to figure it out how). Windows 8 too has few registry settings to be changed mentioned below, but along with this it also stores a unique Hash for every computer. Can any body help me to possibly create this hash for every computer or with some API provided by Microsoft to set default browser ('SetAppAsDefaultAll' does not work). Following are the registry entries.

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.htm\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.AssocFile.HTM  Hash   : XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.html\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.AssocFile.HTM Hash   : XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.xht\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.AssocFile.XHT Hash : XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.xhtml\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.AssocFile.XHT Hash :
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.FTP Hash   : XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.HTTP Hash   : XXXXXXXXXXX
>
> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice
>   Progid : IE.HTTPS Hash   : XXXXXXXXXXX

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: agree, in win7 or earlier, this is not a big deal. Anxious to know how as well.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://superuser.com/questions/498467/why-is-my-default-browser-setting-being-ignored

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all those waiting for answer to this question.

Here you go, looks like that one of the way to do it is through DISM.exe provided by Win 8. Your user should be admin of the machine though.

Using C# code you should be able to run this DISM.exe with specific parameters.

Following blog has the details.

[http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrmlcgn/archive/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-a-gpo-e-g-default-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20130715184141/http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrmlcgn/archive/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-a-gpo-e-g-default-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol.aspx)

Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  It makes sense that the user should be able to automate the process -- the whole point is to stop applications from overriding the user's preferences, not to make administration difficult.

Comment: Of course, the management method used by the administrator is a better topic for SuperUser or ServerFault.  On StackOverflow we deal with code, not group policy.

Comment: agree Ben. But just for those who try to do it by code and do not succeed. This might tell them that its not possible that way.

Comment: `Oops! That page can’t be found.

This page has been disabled.`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is so that the user, not your software, gets to control this setting.

You ought to be able to trigger the "Your computer has new applications for Web Browsing" popup, however, so that the user can easily choose your program if they want.

Comment: well makes sense what you say. But Google is able to do it via chrome :) so even I should be able to that :) Google chrome sets the same registry settings including Hash.

Comment: After installing Google Chrome, I get prompted which browser I want to use.  It isn't changed without my intervention.

Comment: just checked it. yes you are right. Let me confirm if there is no other application which does it without asking user. If I'm not able to find any I will mark your answer correct.

Comment: Adobe still manage to do it the old way on Windows 8.1, and I'm not a hacker so I can't get to the bottom of how they do it. I've analysed the process with API Monitor, and can see them writing to the registry, but no further clues.

If you have Adobe Reader 11, you can trigger it with the following command: c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\AdobeARMHelper.exe /RegisterFileTypesOwnership /PRODUCT:Reader /VERSION:11.0 /INSTALLDIR:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\" /LANG:ENU

This does require a UAC prompt, but doesn't use the new file association UI.

Answer (score 0):

I asked about this too and managed to find a solution, this might be of a help to you since I tested this on Windows 8.1 and it worked:
[How to set the default browser on Windows 7 using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558012/how-to-set-the-default-browser-on-windows-7-using-c)

This actually fits to a case where you want to make any program as the default of it's protocols and file extensions.