# How to focus the specific file type in Windows Settings' file association page

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10

I am trying to associate a specific filetype (eg .doc) to my application. I am currently using `IApplicationActivationManager` to do this as [`IApplicationAssociationRegistration::SetAppAsDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776337(v=vs.85).aspx) method no longer works for Win 8 and above and so is [editing the registry due to the `UserChoice\Hash` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946282/whats-the-hash-in-hkcu-software-microsoft-windows-currentversion-explorer-filee).

This association will be triggered when the user clicks on my app's settings then choosing "Set as default". So far, `IApplicationActivationManager` works for me as it mimics one way on how Windows 10 sets a default file type for an application through "*Settings -> System -> Default apps -> Choose default apps by file type*" when the user chooses to do so.

Is there is a way to focus on the file type programmatically upon opening "*...-> Choose default apps by file type*"? Or better yet, launch programmatically "*...-> Choose default apps by file type -> Choose an app*" dialog for that specific file type?

[image: Screenshot of the 'Choose default apps by file type' Windows Settings pane]

[image: Screenshot of the 'Choose default apps by file type' Windows Settings pane]

Sample code:

```
procedure TForm1.Btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  OPENSETTINGS = 'Windows.ImmersiveControlPanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel';
  PAGESETTINGSBYFILETYPE = 'page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsFileExtensionView';

var
  pAAR: IApplicationActivationManager;
  pid: PDWORD;
  Res: HRESULT;

begin
  Res := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, nil,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IApplicationActivationManager, pAAR);

  if Succeeded(FRes) 
    pAAR.ActivateApplication(OPENSETTINGS, PAGESETTINGSBYFILETYPE, AO_NONE, pid)
  else
    ShowMessage('Failed!');
end;
```

For example, can the command

> page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsFileExtensionView

be extended to scroll to and select a specific file type, something like

> page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsFileExtensionView&‌​filetype=.doc'

? Or some other solution to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to focus a specific file type programmatically, in this example, it's a .doc upon successful launch of Settings -> Choose Default Apps By File Type

Comment: What are you trying to do overall? Create a file association? There's an officially documented way to do that; [check MSDN, under this section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521657(v=vs.85).aspx). Don't try to imitate a user; that won't work and isn't supported. Or are you trying to force yourself as the default despite the user's wishes?

Comment: No, I am not trying to create a new file association. I am trying to associate my project to be set as default for that particular filetype when the user clicks on "Set this app as default" on my projects settings box. It will still be the user's choice. I just thought of minimizing the clicks the user will have to undergo to accomplish this.

Comment: Ah. That's fine, but what you are attempting is still not the right way to do it, as it's prone to changes in future versions of Windows. Does MSDN not help here?

Comment: Just thinking if there is still a command that can be added to this: 'page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsFileExtensionView'

to focus on the file extension, and not have the user scroll down on the list of file types.

ex:
'page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsFileExtensionView&filetype=.doc'

Comment: MSDN does help, some have already been implemented (Open with...). I am adding this method as per the project owner's wishes. If this is how far this method goes, then that's that :)