# NSIS File Associations change in Windows 7

Tags: nsis, file-extension, file-association

I have a requirement to (force) change the file association for a particular file type (extenison ".theext" ) to open with "myapp.exe" when installing an app using NSIS.

I've read a few suggestions of how to achieve this, so currentky this is what I have in my NSIS script:

```
DeleteRegKey HKCR ".theext" 
DeleteRegKey HKLM ".theext" 
DeleteRegKey HKCU ".theext" 

WriteRegStr HKCR ".theext" "" "theextfile"

WriteRegStr HKCR "theextfile" "" "My App Document"

WriteRegStr HKCR "theextfile\DefaultIcon" "" "$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe,0"

WriteRegStr HKCR "theextfile\shell\open\command" "" '"$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe" "%1"'

WriteRegStr HKCR "theextfile\shell\print\command" "" '"$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe" /p "%1"'

WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\RegisteredApplications" "${EXENAME}" "$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe"

WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\RegisteredApplications" "${EXENAME}" "$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe"



WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.theext\OpenWithList" "a" "$INSTDIR\${EXENAME}.exe"
```

To test this, I set the file assoc using WIndows 7 Explorer to GVIM.exe.

Since doing this, every time I run the installer, Windows 7 still opens the file on double click using GVim, and not "MyApp.exe".

But when I check the file associatin as follows, all seems fine:

```
ftype | findstr /i theext
```

Gives:

```
theextfile="C:\Program File (x86)\My App\myapp.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: Used regedit to go hunting. Looks like `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.theext\OpenWithList` has multiple entrie a, b, c, d, e, and the last one of these is GVim. I will look further into this.

Comment: OpenWithList is just extra items you can open with, it does not control the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything you are supposed to do and if the extension is not already registered by somebody else you will become the default. You are not really supposed to delete the old keys first though (it can screw up the system but it will never help you become default). Forcing something is evil, the user is supposed to be in control.

Because people forced this in the past Microsoft starting making it harder to change the default. The undocumented `FileExts` key stores the users chosen default in the `UserChoice` sub-keys. In newer versions of Windows (8+?) the default is verified with some [secret hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946282/whats-the-hash-in-hkcu-software-microsoft-windows-currentversion-explorer-filee) so you cannot override it.

The `IApplicationAssociationRegistration` interface does not work in newer version of Windows but it might work in Windows 7:

```
!include Win\COM.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration} ${IID_IApplicationAssociationRegistration} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    ${IApplicationAssociationRegistration::SetAppAsDefault} $0 '("MyApp", ".myext", ${AT_FILEEXTENSION})'
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
```

In Windows 8 all you can do is launch the generic UI:

```
!include Win\COM.nsh
!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI} ${IID_IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    ${IApplicationAssociationRegistrationUI::LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI} $0 '("Wordpad")' ; Replace with your name from the RegisteredApplications key
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
```

In Windows 10 even this is gone, it will just display a toast telling the user to change their settings if you call LaunchAdvancedAssociationUI.

`ftype` does not know the true default, the default is only known when Windows actually runs the association code in the shell. `IApplicationAssociationRegistration::QueryCurrentDefault` is better at guessing the default but even it can fail if the default is actually a COM shell extension that overrides the default.

Comment: I added a `DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.notebook\UserChoice" ` to clear the UserChoice reg value and now it works. Win 7, will need to test if this works on Win10.