# make an AIR desktop application the default web browser

Tags: air, browser, desktop

I would like to make my AIR desktop browser be the default web browser on a system, how can I go about and do this ?

I would also like to know how I can retrieve the link that has been clicked (in an email for example) to interact with the application.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is impossible in AIR. You can associate your app with file types using the [air-app.xml descriptor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fdc) or by calling `NativeApplication.setAsDefaultApplication()` ([Read about it here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#setAsDefaultApplication%28%29)). Opening files after using either of these methods will trigger your application to launch with an `InvokeEvent` ([Read Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#event:invoke)). You can read a good tutorial for this [here](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/fileassociation/).

However, if I understand correctly, you also want your app to take over any HTTP requests from inside any other app. To do this you have to override the protocol default application, which requires a registry edit and (I believe) that AIR can't do that. You may be able to write an external script in C or Java to do that for you ([This might help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707684/how-to-set-default-browser-in-windows-8-using-c)).