# How to set the default browser on Windows 7 using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, browser

I'm writing a method that receives a browser name and changes the system default to one of the major browsers:

```
public static void SetSystemDefaultBrowser(string aBrowserName)
{
    if (aBrowserName.ToLower() == GetSystemDefaultBrowser().ToLower())
        return;

    switch (aBrowserName.ToLower())
    {
        case "firefox":
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".htm", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".html", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".shtml", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".xht", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@".xhtml", true).SetValue("", "FirefoxHTML");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"http\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
            Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"https\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\http\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Classes\https\shell\open\command", true).SetValue("", "firefox.exe");
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice", true).SetValue("progId", "FirefoxURL");    
            break;
        case "chrome":
            Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--make-default-browser");
            break;
        case "internetexplorer":
           // still can't figure out how to set IE as default...
    }
}
```

In Chrome it's easy and working with command line.

In Firefox there's `-setDefaultBrowser` option that [doesn't work](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/960677), so I need to change all registry keys for that purpose. When I look in Default Programs after using my method for Firefox it shows  that 4 out of 9 defaults were set, so First question is what registry keys am I missing?

And for IE, are those the same registry keys as Firefox or is there another way? ([`shmgrate.exe OcinstallreinstallIE`](https://superuser.com/questions/300770/set-internet-explorer-as-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line) doesn't work on Win7)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an overkill but it simulates user perfectly with UIAutomation and suits my case, here's my solution hopes it helps anybody:

First, I'm running control panel in 'Default Programs' page, then, clicking the 'Set  default programs' link, and then, selecting the browser wanted from the programs list and clicking the 'Set as default' button (You'll need to try yourself to follow...):

```
public static bool SetSystemDefaultBrowserWithGUI(string aBrowserName)
{
    Process.Start("control", "/name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms");
    AutomationElement defaultPrograms = GetSpecificAutomationItem("Default Programs", "Set your default programs");
    var invokePattern = defaultPrograms.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    invokePattern.Invoke();

    AutomationElement browserItem = GetSpecificAutomationItem("Set Default Programs", aBrowserName);
    var invokePattern = browserItem.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
    invokePattern.AddToSelection();

    AutomationElement setButton = GetSpecificAutomationItem("Set Default Programs", "Set this program as default");
    var invokePattern = setButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
    invokePattern.Invoke();

    WindowPattern wpCloseForm = (WindowPattern)GetSpecificWindow("Set Default Programs").GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern);
    wpCloseForm.Close();
}
```

Of course this could be used to make any program the default and it is a good example to UIAutomation. 
BTW, this was tested on Windows 8 and works too.

**Appendix** of the functions used here:

```
public static AutomationElement GetSpecificWindow(string aWinTitle)
{
    AutomationElement mainWindow = null;
    AutomationElementCollection winCollection = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

    foreach (AutomationElement ele in winCollection)
    {
        if (ele.Current.Name.ToLower() == aWinTitle.ToLower())
        {
            mainWindow = ele;
            break;
        }
    }
    return mainWindow;
}

public static AutomationElement GetSpecificAutomationItem(string aWinTitle, string itemName)
{
    AutomationElement window = GetSpecificWindow(aWinTitle);      
    Condition condition = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, itemName);
    return window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Descendants, condition);
}
```

*All of this will work better when optimized for yourself with `Thread.Sleep()` `try/catch` etc...